# Downloading CSV downloads all files, need it to download specific ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm having a little trouble downloading values to a CSV file.  I have two models, downtowns and properties. Downtowns have many properties. Properties each have one downtown.  Problem i'm having is that with what i've done i've been able to download all properties, which is cool! But what I'm struggling with is downloading only properties owned by the downtown.

To what I have initially to download all properties I have

In my properties controller:

```
  def index
    @properties = Property.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @properties.to_csv }
    end
  end
```

In my properties model

```
  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w(id name owner_first_name created_at)
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |property|
        csv << property.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
      end
    end
  end
```

and then in my view I have.

```
= link_to "download CSV", downtown_properties_path(:format => :csv), class: "button"
```

So again this works, but because of my associations the view where i can add my link can only be in `downtowns/1/properties` which based on my putting the code in the `index` this actually makes sense

I tried something along the lines of

```
@download_properties = Property.where(downtown: @downtown_id)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @download_properties.to_csv }
end
```

However `@downtown_id` is not defined at this point. So I think the solution is better in the `downtown` model?

If anyone has any idea looking through this and able to help me out, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: where the downtown_id is defined?

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be:

```
@download_properties = Property.where(downtown: params[:id])
```

or

```
@download_properties = Downtown.find(params[:id]).properties
```